# Extract specific attribute from son with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Good morning. I'm trying to solve a problem with NODE.js. I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "AAL": {
    "name": "Aalborg Airport",
    "country": "DK",
    "timeZone": "DK",
    "latitude": "570535N",
    "longitude": "0095100E"
  },
  "AAR": {
    "name": "Aarhus",
    "country": "DK",
    "timeZone": "DK",
    "latitude": "561800N",
    "longitude": "0103708E"
  }
}
```

Writing a .pug file in NODE.js I have to extract "AAR" and "AAL". The .pug file receives an array containing JSON "objects". I tried with something like:

```
extends base.pug

block content
  div(style="margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;")#body
    h1 titolo_pagina
    ul
      each place in airportsList
        li
          a(href="./airport/:" + place.id) #{place.name}
```

But with "place.id" I'm not able to obtain what I want.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this : `ul
        each place, key in airportsList

            li
                a(href="./airport/:" + key) #{place.name}` (see here : https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)